# iex: run compiled elixir binary in iex console

Tags: compilation, binary, console, erlang, elixir

I have binary file compiled using `mix release`: `bin/app`.

How can I run it using `iex` so that I will be attached to process console and will be able to call functions from `bin/app`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

- [**`bin/foo start_iex`**](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html?#module-bin-release_name-commands)
- connect to the running remote from `iex` (for this the application should have been started named.)

Assuming the application was run as `foo@192.168.1.42`, and local host is `192.168.1.10`, this would open a remote shell:

```
iex --name remote@192.168.1.10 \
    --remsh foo@192.168.1.42 \
    --cookie COOKIE
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can I list all erl applications on the node?

Comment: [`Application.loaded_applications/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#loaded_applications/0) for the current application, the whole `:application` erlang module for more.